# How do I unlock the military backpack?

Tags: the-last-of-us

By playing through on hard+ difficulty, will I be able to unlock the military backpack, or does it have to be a new game?

Answer (score 3):

The military backpack unlocks as a purchasable skin after beating the game on Hard or Survivor. New Game + should work. You would, however, have to be playing on one of those difficulties from the beginning of the game - you can't switch to or from a lower difficulty before finishing and expect to get the unlock.

You'll still need to spend $1000 of the metagame currency to purchase it for use after unlocking.